# MongoDB 2.6.12 - no collections in DB

Tags: mongodb

I have a some problem with MongoDB (2.6.12). I have one database with collections and a lot of data. Then I created user with `readWrite` role, enabled `auth=true` in `mongod.conf`, restarted 'mongod' service.

Looks like auth works fine, but I can't see any data/collections in DB. I can't use 'find' query, in mongo shell it just returns nothing (empty line). I also can connect to DB without credentials and I see the same result.

I've tried a different roles and different users, but I can't get access to my data. What can be a problem?

Comment: Are you sure the `dbpath` is correct ? Do you have replica sets ?

Comment: @MickaëlB "Are you sure the dbpath is correct ?"  Oh my :) Thank you, this was a problem

Answer (score 1):

OK!

1. When you login, you need to use --authenticationDatabase -parameter, normal value for that is 'admin'.

> mongo host:port -u user -p password --authenticationDatabase admin

2. If authentication database is not same database where your collection is (your collection is not at admin-database) give that database name as last parameter at 'mongo'-command, to select that DB.

> mongo host:port -u user -p password --authenticationDatabase admin myOwnDB

OR

2. after successful login, use command: 'use your_db_name', to change that database.

> use myOwnDB

IF you don't know your database name.
When you have login successful, give command 'show dbs' to list all databases.

> show dbs

After that you can use command 'use db_name' to change database.  Then you can use command 'show collections' to list all collections on that database.

> use myOwnDB
>
> show collections